# How i load text from a file?

Tags: python

I want that the game keeps the Highscore in a file called Highscore.txt
 and i want that highscore = highscore.txt
I used this command -->`h = font.render("Your Highscore is {} points!".format(highscore), True, (237, 205, 99))`

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

When I got your question right and you just want to read and write to a .txt file you can do it like this:

```
Reading a file:
openFile = open("path", "r")     The "r" means read

Writing to a File:
writeToFile = open("path", "w")     The "w" means write
writeToFile.write("yourText")
```

And after opening a file you always have to `close()` your files like this:

```
openFile.close()
```

and:

```
writeToFile.close()
```

I hope that is what you are searching for.